# How do I access the documentation for a specific version (ie v1.11.13) of AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, documentation, aws-cli

Its always possible to access the docs for the `latest` version of AWS CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/list-tables.html

However I cant find any documentation for **older** versions.

Say for example if I wanted to access v1.11.13, then I would expect the following URL:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1.11.13/reference/dynamodb/list-tables.html

But the URL above does not seem to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Not ideal but if you can't locate the docs, maybe simply install the relevant version of the awscli and run `aws dynamodb list-tables help`. I can't imagine that specific function has changed much, however.

Comment: As @jarmod says - plus you do realise that the CLI is just an interface to the API?

Comment: If you really want to, you can pull down the awscli git repo, sync to a specific version's tag, then [build the html](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/develop/doc) documentation to have a local copy to view.